# How to respawn vpnc when it stops?

Tags: cron, root, vpn, init.d

As root, I've setup a crontab rule that launches vpnc everyday early in the morning (before I arrive at my workplace). But it often occurs that the vpn stopped mid day. As a result, I have to `sudo vpnc ...` in order to relaunch the background process.

How to make the vpnc respawn automatically?

Maybe initab respawn rules or something like that? How would you do? What is the preferable way to do that please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put a simple cron script together that would monitor to see if the vpnc process is still up. If not, then run it.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(pidof vpnc)" ]; then 
  echo "restart"
  ..run vpnc here..
else 
  echo "running"
  ..do nothing..
fi
```

Once you've created this script, call it `/etc/cron.d/vpnc_checker.bash` and create a crontab entry for it, in the file `/etc/crontab`. This will run every 5 minutes.

```
*/5  *  *  *  * root  /etc/cron.d/vpnc_checker.bash
```

Make sure the script is executable:

```
$ chmod +x /etc/cron.d/vpnc_checker.bash
```

Comment: `*/5 * * * *` for every 5 minutes, rather than `5 * * * *`, right?

Comment: @CupawnTae yes, thanks for the catch. Fixed!